# In practice, is there a limit to the insulating properties of a transistor acting as switch?

Tags: switches, insulation

I would like to know if there a limit to the insulating properties of a transistor acting as switch?

Comment: the answer is "yes". But I don't think that is what you meant to ask for – please specify what kind of switch you're asking about, and what kind of current you switch.

Comment: PS: Welcome to Electronics.SE :) We're happy you're here, we just tend to be better at specifically asking specific questions :)

Comment: I am sorry I wasn't clear! I am studying about transistors acting as switches. I got this question in the tutorial but I didn't know the answer from the Internet.

Comment: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/What-is-VCEO-transistor-rating

Answer (score 4):

There is a limit to the insulating properties of *everything* - air, rubber, glass, switches, transistors, everything. This is called the "insulation breakdown voltage".

Exactly how high it is depends on the device. The breakdown voltage for tiny transistors can be as small as a few volts.

Answer (score 4):

Transistors are based on semiconductor junctions, and thus have what we typically call a *breakdown voltage*. It varies, depending on the transistor, from less than 5 V to multiple kV. You'll need to look up the numbers in your transistor's datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

One must not forget that the signal frequency affects the transistor insulation as well. For instance, a RF signal cannot be switched by transistors, you need either a relay (for low speed switching) or PIN diodes (for high speed switching). 
That said, your switch insulation may drop drastically if the signal frequencies are too high.

Answer (score 0):

Transistors can be used as switches for RF, if the RF rides atop a DC pedestal.

A diffpair works fine [I've seen this in mixer/modulator/multipler ICs] to steer the DC+RF to the left or right.

The capacitive properties will set the high-frequency "insulating" behavior.